# $sup_x [ f(x)+sup_x g(x)]= sup_x[f(x)+g(x)]$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$sup_x [ f(x)+sup_x g(x)]= sup_x[f(x)+g(x)]$ is the statement correct?

Can I prove like this:

$sup_x [ f(x)+sup_x g(x)] = sup_x[f(x)] + sup_x[g(x)] = sup[f(x)+g(x)]$.

Comment: In general you only have $\sup\{f(x) + g(x)\} \leq sup\{f(x)\} + sup\{g(x)\}$

Comment: @echzhen When will equality occur? Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

The equality is NOT true. Let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1 - x,$ and use $[0,1]$ for their domains.

Then $\;\sup_x[f(x) + \sup_xg(x)] = 2\;$ and $\;\sup_x[f(x) + g(x)] = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = x = -g(x)$ in $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Take $f(x)=1_{\left\lbrace x=1\right\rbrace}$ and $g(x)=1_{\left\lbrace x=2\right\rbrace}$. 
Then :

$$sup_x [ f(x)+sup_x g(x)]=sup_x [ f(x)+1]=2$$ 
But :
$$sup_x[f(x)+g(x)]=1$$

Comment: What does $1_{\{x=\cdot\}}$ mean?

Comment: This is the indicator function. (yes my notation is a bit redundant)